# Get the sprite position data and pass to next scene

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

IS that possible to get the sprite position data and pass it to next scene?

Scene 1

```
    preload() {
        this.load.image('neutral_emoji', '/image/neutral.png');
        this.load.image('sad_emoji', '/image/sad.png');
        this.load.image('happy_emoji', '/image/smiley.png');
    }

    create() {
        var emoji = ['sad_emoji', 'happy_emoji'];
        this.neutral = this.add.image(0, 0, 'neutral_emoji');
        this.emotion = this.add.image(0, 0, emoji[Math.floor(Math.random() * emoji.length)]);
        this.aGrid = new AlignGrid({scene: this,rows: 11,cols: 11});
        this.aGrid.placeAtIndex(57,this.neutral);
        this.aGrid.placeAtIndex(63,this.emotion);
        Align.scaleToGameW(this.neutral,.1);
        Align.scaleToGameW(this.emotion,.1);
     }
```

As the code above the neutral emoji is placed at position 57 and sad/smiley is placed at 63.I would like to pass the position data and texture key to Scene 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending how you are starting the next `scene`, but **yes**, just can pass the `data` you want to pass, to the next `scene` as parameter

```
// first Scene 'data' to pass
this.scene.start('NextScene', {key:'texure_key', x: 1, y: 1});
```

This parameter will be passed to the function calls of methods `init` and `create`, so you can retrieve the data from that parameter.

```
// Next Scene
function create( data ){
    // ...
}

function init( data ){
    // ...
}
```